# No bootloader menu after a dual boot install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Today I added a second physical disk to my PC on which to install Ubuntu (other disk has Win 10).

I noticed during the installation that no other OS was found on my PC, but I ignored it and kept installing on the new hard drive.

On restarting, I don't get a GRUB menu, it just boots straight to Ubuntu.

If I press F11 (my PC boot menu) and select the other hard drive, it boots into Win 10.

So I went into the BIOS and made my original HD the first choice for boot, and my PC boots into Windows on reboot.

Can someone help me figure out why the Ubuntu setup didn't detect Windows during setup?

I installed the grub customizer tool, and that too cannot see Windows.

Comment: Most often issue is Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag. Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Other possibility is you installed in different boot mode, all system need to be UEFI boot or all BIOS boot.

Comment: @oldfred so likely solution is to disable fast startup and reinstall ubuntu from the start? Or is there a shortcut?

Comment: If issue is fast startup in Windows, you just need to boot into Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu & run `sudo update-grub` That runs the os-prober which then should see Windows. But if issue is something else that will not work. Are both installs UEFI?